# change backgroung colour of div when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a UI & here i am not able to format it properly.
Two things i am not able to do :--

1. left-1, left-2, left-3 .. text is comming at the bottom of the
   button image. I want them to come at the right of the image ?
2. Whwen ever i press button on the left is it possible to change the
   background colour of the  in which image & text (i.e for left-1
   & left-2) is placed ?

How can i acive this.

Code :--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">

<head>
<style>
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
.input {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
.input input {
    display: block;
}
.imgtxt {
    margin: 0;
    font-family:arial;
    color:#DDDFED;
    font-size:15px;
}
#images {
    background-color:#888686;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
div.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

div.scrollableMenu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#Menu {
    background-color:#292B3B;
    position:absolute;
    top:124px;
    bottom:20px;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
}
#center {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    position:absolute;
    top:124px;
    left:200px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:20px;
}
#fotter {
    background-color:#CC99FF;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body >


<body>
    <div id="images" class="scrollable">
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" title="Room one" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-1</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-2</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#00FF00;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-3</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-4</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" title="Room one" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-5</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-6</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-7</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-8</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-9</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" title="Room one" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-10</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-11</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-12</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-13</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-14</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" title="Room one" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-15</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-16</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-17</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-18</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Keypad-19</p>
            <hr style="border-color:#DDDFED; background-color:#DDDFED;align="left";width="80px"; size="4px";">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Menu" class="scrollableMenu">
        <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" title="Room one" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-left : 16px;">Left-1</p>
        </div >
        <hr/>
        <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-left : 16px;" >Left-2</p>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-left : 16px;" >Left-3</p>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-left : 16px;" >Left-4</p>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-left : 16px;" >Left-5</p>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-left : 16px;" >Left-6</p>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-left : 16px;" >Left-7</p>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
    <div id="center">Table center</div>
    <div id="fotter">Copyright © 2014 My First Layout</div>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/

Comment: the main problem here is that you are using internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1:** For placing the text to the right, you can use the `float` property of `css`

**Part 2:** and for changing the color, you can use for example `Jquery`.

**Code(*I am not using the correct identifiers. Just giving a basic idea what can solve your issues...*)**

Css code for part 1:

```
input {
float:left;
clear:both;
}

.imgtxt {
float:right;
}
```

Jquery code for part 2:

```
$("button").clicked(function() {
    $("#Your-Div-to-change-color").css({'background':'#ddd'});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For left-1, left-2, left-3 .. text ...

Simply Float the things . For Instance assign width to image or other container [if any u using] and also float the text .....Keep in mind the width ..... and also do clear float element after Text.

For Example

```
#menu > div > input {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
```

[or suit your self but dont left the width of image & text beyound 100%]

```
#menu > div > p.imgtxt {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}

#menu > div:after {
  clear:both;
}
```

OR

```
#menu  hr {
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquerys [parent method](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get the node that was clicked. Add a css class like so

JS

```
$('.input input').click(function (){
  $(this).parent().addClass('selected');

});
```

CSS

```
.input.selected{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other people have answered with what I would have suggested, I thought I’d post something useful.

Just about every tag other than `<DIV>` and `<SPAN>` automatically has a return after.

Example:

```
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p> Hello </p>
```

The word Hello will always be below the Title because there is an automatic return `<br />` set on the `<H1>`

Using the `Float:` in your CSS will avoid this happening.